# XSLT Custom Sorting using XSLT 1.0

Tags: sorting, xslt

This is a sample from an XML document.

```
<A>
  <Value>B2.B1-1.C2-0.D20</Value>
</A>
<A>
  <Value>A2.B15-1.C2-0.D20</Value>
</A>
<A>
  <Value>A2.B2-1.C2-0.D20</Value>
</A>
```

and so on.

I need to sort this to look like

A2.B2-1.C2-0.D20
A2.B15-1.C2-0.D20
B2.B1-1.C2-0.D20

The number of dot separated components are not known and the numbers in them can be in any format (1-1,11,11abcd). The sorting is intuitive as one would normally expect. First it is based on letters and the numbers are bunched together and read (B2 and B15 is the correct order. The lexical order B15 , B2 is not correct)

Can this be done with XSLT 1.0 ?

Comment: I'm assuming you have no control over the input document?

Comment: Why does B1-1 come after B15-1? Seems like a contradiction!

Comment: The B1-1 is actually preceded by B2; the B15-1 is preceded by A2, which obviously comes before B2.

Comment: Yes I have no control over the input document. I could add other sequence numbers if I had control. And flynn is right with the clarification. I am sorry about the format of the output I typed. It should have read A2.B2-1.C2-0.D20    ,  A2.B15-1.C2-0.D20  ,     B2.B1-1.C2-0.D20

Comment: So, shoud 1-1 and 11 be considered equal? Or should 1-1 precede 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT doesn't define precisely how sorting should operate; the results are implementation-defined.

In recent releases of Saxon there is a collation that does what you want, but that assumes XSLT 2.0; in fact it assumes Saxon.

Doing it in a portable way in XSLT 1.0 is not easy, especially as you can't call out to recursive templates to compute the sort key.

Comment: Is there a C based implementation of XSLT 2.0 that you are aware of ? I am running this in a C based environment.

Comment: No, there's a big gap in the market here for someone who wants to spend a couple of years writing sofware that everyone wants to use and no-one wants to pay for.